# jQuery avoid code repetition

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing a small plug in and is it possible to avoid writing the same function twice?

```
if(opts.effect === 'fade'){
                            // fade effect
                            (opts.overlay).children().fadeOut(opts.time_fadeOut).promise().done(function () {
                                overlay_content.fadeIn();
                            });     
                            //don't need to make the overlay fadeIn every time
                            (opts.overlay).fadeIn();
}

else if(opts.effect === 'slide'){
                            // sldie up/down effect
                            (opts.overlay).children().fadeOut(opts.time_fadeOut).promise().done(function () {
                               overlay_content.delay(500).fadeIn();
                            });
                            (opts.overlay).slideDown();
}
```

Is there a better way of using an if stament? [full-script](http://jsfiddle.net/uKfqX/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try determining the function using `opts.effect` and use it like `(opts.overlay)[effect]();`

```
var effect = (opts.effect === 'fade')?'fadeIn':'slideDown';
var cBfx = (opts.effect === 'fade')?fadeCB:slideCB;

(opts.overlay).children().fadeOut(opts.time_fadeOut).promise().done(cBfx );

(opts.overlay)[effect]();

function slideCB () { overlay_content.delay(500).fadeIn(); }

function fadeCB() {  overlay_content.fadeIn(); }
```

Comment: The callback is different for each case as well